# Folder Watcher doesn't trigger always with a large number of files

Tags: uwp, filesystemwatcher

OnContentsChanged doesn't trigger when folder has a large number of pictures (eg: 200).

```
QueryOptions folderOptions = new QueryOptions()
                {
                    FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep
                };
                folderQuery = windowsFolder.CreateFolderQueryWithOptions(folderOptions);
                folderQuery.ContentsChanged += OnContentsChanged;
                await folderQuery.GetFoldersAsync();

 private void OnContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
        {
            doSomething();
        }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I tested with Pictures Library which has almost 400 pictures. `ContentsChanged` event works well in my side. Could you share more details or steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi Jay, 

Could you try to delete 300 images all at once, and check this scenario... I'm asking this because if I try dl to delete few images (until 100) the error doesn't happen. 

Thanks